# accurately cropping image via saliency map

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm using Itti's saliency map. So given an example image, I could get a salient map as shown below(compare the saliency map with the color photo):
[image]
The problem is that although the algorithms pinpoints roughly where the salient object is, it fails to reliably get the dimensions of the object. Thus, if I want my program to automatically crop out the most salient object in an image, I can only speculate the dimensions based on the shape of the salient map for the object. This is pretty unreliable since the salient shape could vary greatly.

Are there more reliable methods to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In order to find a better estimate of the salient objects' boundaries, I suggest you'd use some foreground extraction algorithm. One popular algorithm for that task is called [GrabCut](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/visionimagevideoediting/segmentation/grabcut.htm). It requires an initial estimate of the object boundaries. For the task in hand, the initial estimate would be the boundaries of the blobs from the saliency map.